# using $mdDialog as a service with template and directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I want to implement a dialog service which will display a $mdDialog with its template and with a directive as a content. I achieved to do it as follows. In my service file :

```
dialog.show = function(directive){
        $mdDialog.show({
            template: directive,
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            clickOutsideToClose:false
        });
    };
```

this code works, however there are some issues :

1. I have to repeat dialog's header/footer in each directives
2. my dialog has a scrollbar that scrolls header, footer and content all together,
   the proper behaviour is to keep header/footer fixed and scroll only
   the content

What I would like to do is something like:

service.js

```
import tmpl from './template.html

...

    dialog.show = function(directive){

            $mdDialog.show({
                template: temp,
                controller: function() {
                    this.directive = directive
                },
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                clickOutsideToClose:false
            });
        };
```

template.html

```
<md-dialog>
    <form>
        <md-toolbar>
...
        </md-toolbar>
        <md-dialog-content>
            {{vm.directive}}
        </md-dialog-content>
        <md-dialog-actions>
...
        </md-dialog-actions>
    </form>
</md-dialog>
```

Is it possible? how can I inject directive into a template file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this be defining a custom directive for the dialog's content and injecting it into the template. For example:

**modal-directive.js**

```
angular.module('yourApp')
  .directive('modalDirective', function() {
    // define directive here
  });
```

**template.html**

```
<md-dialog>
    <form>
        <md-toolbar>
...
        </md-toolbar>
        <md-dialog-content>
            <!-- Add the directive to the template -->
            <modal-directive></modal-directive>
        </md-dialog-content>
        <md-dialog-actions>
...
        </md-dialog-actions>
    </form>
</md-dialog>
```

Comment: yes, that's what I would like to do. the problem is that the modal content will change. for example when I'm on customer page I would like to inject `<modal-directive-customer>` and for company page would be `<modal-directive-company>`. Is it possible ?